# error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T> T SmartIO::Peek() {
    T temp;
    T tempReturn;

    while(true){
        temp = *(T*)&buffer[ptrSeek];

        if(temp !=0){
            ptrSeek++;
            tempReturn += *(T*)&buffer[ptrSeek];
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }

    return tempReturn;
}
```

so what i want to do is , start reading from ptrSeek start looping, adding the value to temp and check if temp's value !=0 add this value to tempReturn, and once the temp's value is 0 break the loop and return the tempReturnbut, but it's keep giving me this error :

```
error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

how can i solve this issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a fundamental issue with your template code if you are attempting to compare an arbitrary type `T` against the numeric constant 0, which you are doing in the code here:

```
T temp;

/* ... */

if(temp != 0){
     /* ... */
}
```

The problem here is that `T` is an arbitrary type (in this case, you seem to be instantiating the template with `std::string`), but you are expecting that type to be comparable to 0.  This is perfectly fine - it just restricts `T` to be types that can be compared against 0 - but from the fact that you're reporting this as an error I'm not sure if you're aware of this.

Your options are either to not instantiate this template with `std::string` as an argument (the way it's written, I don't think you're supposed to be able to do this, since it looks like the function keeps adding values together of some type), or to debug the template and change its behavior.  I'm not quite sure what you want the code to do, so in the latter case I'm not sure how I can assist.

Hope this clarifies things!

Comment: all i wanna do is to check if temp has a value or not if it doesn't has a value i will break the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "has a value or not?"  Everything has a value.  Do you mean whether it has some specific value that you care about?

Comment: well i wanted it to return the next available character , that was my main point then i wanted to make it as template so i can return the next available type i pass it to the template!

Answer (score 0):

You can **specialize or overload** the comparison part (here `!=`) for the types which are not directly comparable to `0`. Just an example,

```
template<typename T>
bool NotEqualto0 (const T& obj) { return (obj != 0); }

// overload for std::string    
bool NotEqualto0 (const std::string &s) { return (s.c_str() != 0); }

...
if(NotEqualto0(temp))
...
```

[Above function is hardwired for `0`; it can be generalized as per need.]

Comment: this lagged my whole pc it used my whole ram and cpu forced me to restart the PC!

Comment: @MixedCoder, it should not happen. I don't see anything wrong in the code, I have posted. Is the string formation happening improperly.