# binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand

Tags: c++

Ok so I have read multiple instances of this question on Stack Overflow, but I cannot seem to find an answer that relates to my project.
[binary-no-operator found which takes left handed operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936409/error-c2678-binary-no-operator-found-which-takes-a-left-hand-operand)

What I cannot seem to figure out why I can use the equality operator on say 2 ints but not between the two object files that this program is written for.
Here's a snip from the class:

```
template <class Type>
class stackType: public stackADT<Type>
{
public:
  const stackType<Type>& operator=(const stackType<Type>&); 
  stackType(const stackType<Type>& otherStack); 
  ~stackType(); 
  bool operator== (const stackType<Type>&) const;
private:
  int maxStackSize; //variable to store the maximum stack size
  int stackTop;     //variable to point to the top of the stack
  Type *list;       //pointer to the array that holds the stack elements
};

template<class Type>
bool stackType<Type>::operator==(const stackType<Type & right) const
{ 
  //assuem the stacks have same number of elements
  if(this->stacKTop != right.stackTop)
    return false;
  //check for eqaulity
  for (int i=0; i<stackTop; i++)
    if (this->list[i] != right.list[i])
      return false;
  return true;
 }//end operator function
```

main program to test:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  stackType<int> s1(12);
  stackType<int>s2(15);    
  for (int i=3; i<30; i+=3)
  {
    s1.push(i);
    s2.push(i);
  }//end for
  if(s1 == s2)
    cout<<"both stacks are equal"<<endl;
  else
    cout<<"stacks are not equal"<<endl;
}
```

I am using visual studio 2012 and I am just confused and burned out.  I have tried changing the declaration I have added the keyword const to the declarations, I added more arguments, nothing.  I tested the equality operator on two ints and it compiled and worked.  Again I want to learn from my mess up so all input is welcome.

Comment: Wall of code attack! Whatever happened to making  **minimal example** of your problem?

Comment: I removed the bulk of the code to clean it up

Comment: `(const stackType<Type & right) const`  You missed a `>`.  @MarkStevens There is a `==` both declared and defined.

Comment: [The code works](http://ideone.com/TTKZV) if you remove the mysterious `public stackADT<Type>` and fix some syntax errors.

Comment: Where the definition of the `==` operator for `stackType`?

Comment: @Craig: wait really?  That was it?  A missing `>`?

Comment: No it wasn't, but it still was causing some issues

Comment: Show us the declaration of the operator `==` in the class. Together with the class definition. I see you have already posted the declaration itself, but the context is missing. Post the entire class definition.

Comment: @AndreyT: I edited back in the code I felt was relevant.  Previously the entire program was posted.

Comment: @Craig: wait, if the `>` wasn't the problem, what _is_ the problem you are having?

Comment: @Craig: Aside from some unrelated issues with missing declarations and syntax typos, the code compiles perfectly fine for me.

Comment: There was some weird syntax mistakes and some minor issues I glossed over like removing the abstract class declaration

Answer (score 1):

The code works if you define `public stackADT<Type>` as an empty class, which implies that that probably shouldn't be there, or that you have some other wierdness with the code.

As far as syntax: in `(const stackType<Type & right) const` You missed a `>`.  Also, you misspelled `stackTop` as `stacKTop` at one point.

Comment: Thank you to both Mooing Duck and Jesse Good , this has solved the problem.  public stackADT was supposed to be an abstract class that I forgot to remove when I started.  Again thank you